# Looping function

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables:

Table A of customer data

```
ID -  Name     -   Age
1  -  Joe      -   24
2  -  Bloggs   -   46
```

Table B is a temp table of random numbers

```
ID - RandomNumber
1  - 68
2  - 46
3  - 49
4  - 24
```

I need to select from table A

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a WHERE a.age = [randomNumber from tableB]
```

The where clause needs to look into tableB. Looks at first random number - 68, does this exist in Age column of tableA, no, so move to next random number. does 46 exist in tableB, yes, it then returns 2 - Bloggs - 46, and inserts that row into another table.

the process starts again but from where is left off - does 49 exist in tableA, no, so next, does 24 exist in tableA, yes, copy that row into other table.

I have a list of 150 students, and want to randomly select 30 by age.

I could use `RAND()` function, but number will change every time, so id rather place random numbers in a table first, and then look up.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add some more sample table data, and also specify the wanted output.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Do you want to insert the names of the 30 first matched rows of Table B ?

Comment: I want something that will iterate through tableB to match with tableA

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to randomly order the output rows, `ORDER BY RAND()` is your friend:

```
SELECT sub.* FROM (
  SELECT ta.ID,
    ta.Name,
    ta.Age,
    ROWNUM num
  FROM TABLEA ta
    JOIN TABLEB tb ON ta.Age = tb.RandomNumber
    ORDER BY RAND() ) sub
  WHERE sub.num <=30
```

This will retrieve maximum 30 randomly selected names from your table A

Note: if you are using a DBMS where `LIMIT` is implemented, you can simplify the query and simply use

```
  SELECT ta.ID,
    ta.Name,
    ta.Age
  FROM TABLEA ta
    JOIN TABLEB tb ON ta.Age = tb.RandomNumber
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT tableA.name FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.age IN (SELECT RandomNumber FROM tableB)
```

If you need only 30 students, you should also add

```
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9f7d/3) you can find an example for your request.

```
select top 30 * from TableA where Age in (select RandomNumber from TableB)
```